# Prove that a regular map is not an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> **Problem:** Let $X$ be an algebraic curve defined by $y^2= x^3$ and $f(t) =(t^2, t^3)$ the regular map $\mathbb{A}^1 \to X$. Prove that $f$ is not an isomorphism. What are the rational functions in $t$ that correspond to the functions in the local ring of the point $(0,0)$?

---

**My attempt:** I tried to construct the inverse as $P(x) + Q(x)y$ with $P(x), Q(x)$ polynomials, because every regular function on $X$ can be written uniquely in this form, but I have trouble constructing the inverse. By writing $x= t^2$ and $y= t^3$ and composing the two functions I got $P(t^2) + Q(t^2)t^3$ and I think I should prove that this last expression is not equal to $t$ for no $P$ or $Q$, but I’m stuck.

For the last question, I wrote the local ring $O_x= \left\{ \frac{P_1(x) + Q_1(x)y}{P_2(x)} \right\}$, with $P_2$ having a nonzero constant term. How do I express now the rational functions in $t$ corresponding to that?

Comment: Hint: $P(t^2)=\cdots+p_2t^4+p_1t^2+p_0$. Do the same thing for $Q$. This should make whether you can get $t$ out of this clear. Your local ring at the end has big issues: why not try writing down the local ring in terms of $x$ and $y$ and then making the substitution?

Comment: I don’t know if I’m catching the hint, but by writing out the polynomials as you suggested, it looks like $t$ cannot be a term of the expression, since there are only higher powers of $t$

Comment: For the local ring: do you mean that the expression should be more explicit in $x$ and $y$ or is it wrong all the way?

Comment: Yes, $t$ can't appear in that expression, so it can't be equal to $t$. For the local ring, proceed as in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798947/determining-the-local-ring-of-a-curve) with $x$ and $y$, and then make the substitution to write things in terms of $t$.